# Sherlock ActionBar onActivityResult not called in Fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

In my app I have a SherlockFragmentActivity which is hosting an actionbar with 4 tabs. Each of the tabs is a SherlockFragment. Calling a normal Activity from one of the tabs (let's say Tab1) is working fine with startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);

But my onActivityResult in Tab1 is never called.
After reading lots of topics I understood that onActivityResult of my main activity is called first, which indeed is. But I can't get the values beeing past to the onActivityResult of my fragment.

Here is my code...

Main Activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1.class.getName());
    mFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Also tried it with super call in line one and without super call.

Fragment:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(requestCode == 0) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //do some stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried with super call at the beginning and at the end.

Everytime I get the same error:

```
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65536, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.BlubBlub.TimeMate/com.BlubBlub.TimeMate.TimeMateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3267)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3310)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:142)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4930)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at com.BlubBlub.TimeMate.Tab1.onActivityResult(Tab1.java:125)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at com.BlubBlub.TimeMate.TimeMateActivity.onActivityResult(TimeMateActivity.java:150)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
09-09 14:33:34.230: E/AndroidRuntime(7408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3263)
```

What is the correct way to get this to work? I'm really desperate by now...

Comment: Ok, after some more testing, I got it to work. If I reinstanciate all global variables from my fragment that are used in its onActivityResult method it's working. But that can't be the way it's supposed to be! Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new instance of your Fragment. This instance is not attached to the Activity, so getActivity() returns null. It is also not the Fragment currently displayed in your tab.

When starting an Activity from a Fragment, you have to use [Fragment#startActivityForResult(Bundle, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). FragmentActivity will then handle dispatching it to the right Fragment for you. You do not have to do this manually.

When using startActivityForResult, make sure you always check that resultCode matches the one you passed to startActivityForResult before doing anything.

Comment: But that's what I tried first. Did a test again: removed onActivityResult completely from my main activity. My startActivityForResult method is already the fragment one (from the support library). It's still crashing. But seems to be always crashing on the first line, where I use a variable of my fragment. Maybe another hint?

Comment: THANK YOU. This solved my problem! I was working on it now for two hours. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace says that you have a NullPointerException in the Toast class, so I dont think it's a problem receiving the `onActivityResult()` callback exactly.

My guess would be your passing a null context to the `Toast.makeText()` call

If your showing a Toast from an Activity, do:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If your showing a Toast form a fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you do this, the Context you pass to `Toast.makeText()` shouldn't be null and you'll avoid this exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. Tried it with Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); But gives me the same error

Comment: With an empty onActivityCreate Method in my fragment at least there is no crash. But as soon as it is not empty anymore, it crashes...

Answer (score 0):

Try call `Fragment.startActivityForResult`, not `Fragment.getActivity().startActivityForResult` if you did so. See the android source code and notice the deference.

```
//Fragment.java
////////////////
/**
 * Call {@link Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)} on the fragment's
 * containing Activity.
 */
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    if (mActivity == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to Activity");
    }
    mActivity.startActivityFromFragment(this, intent, requestCode);
}

// FragmentActivity.java
////////////////////////
/**
 * Called by Fragment.startActivityForResult() to implement its behavior.
 */
public void startActivityFromFragment(Fragment fragment, Intent intent, 
        int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == -1) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, -1);
        return;
    }
    if ((requestCode&0xffff0000) != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode");
    }
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, ((fragment.mIndex+1)<<16) + (requestCode&0xffff));
}
```